# cannot find symbol - compile errors

Tags: java, for-loop, calculator

So the goal is the calculate the amount of interest (10%) accumulated after 3 months based on the user's input. However, I am getting too many errors. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class showCase {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            int x = ((amount * 10) / 100);
            int result = amount - x; 
            amount = result;
        }
            System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

```
./Playground/showCase.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                for(i=0; i< 3; i++) {
                    ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class showCase
./Playground/showCase.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                for(i=0; i< 3; i++) {
                         ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class showCase
./Playground/showCase.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                for(i=0; i< 3; i++) {
                               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class showCase
./Playground/showCase.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(result);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable result
  location: class showCase
4 errors
```

Comment: Read the errors, they are telling you exactly what is missing. For `result`, take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp).

Comment: You are missing the variable declaration for `i`. Also, `result` is declared inside the for loop and is therefore out of scope for the `System.out.println()` which is outside the for loop.

Comment: Which part not finding symbol `i` because you haven't declared it anywhere is are to understand?

Comment: `int x = ((amount * 10) / 100);` - you are going to have trouble with integer division

Answer (score -1):

### Declaration

You forgot to declare the `i` variable.

For that, simply prefix it with the type.

```
int i = 0
// instead of just
i = 0
```

---

### Scope

Also, your final print

```
System.out.println(result);
```

is trying to use the variable `result` which is local to the loop. So it does not exist outside of the loop anymore. You have to create it before the loop:

```
int result = ...
for (...) {

}
System.out.println(result);
```

---

### Int division

Finally, this line will not compute what you expect:

```
int x = ((amount * 10) / 100);
```

The problem here is that you demand integer division, so `int / int` which yields an `int` as well, so rounded down. Basically `1 / 3` is `0`.

You have to work with floating point numbers, like a `double` instead.

```
double x = ((amount * 10) / 100.0;
```

Also note the `100.0` which makes it a `double`.

Answer (score -1):

All comments give you correct answer, but to be clear.
First if you declare anything inside for loop, it will stay there. You can not call it outside for. So you have to do it before for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class showCase {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            int x = ((amount * 10) / 100);
            result = amount - x; 
            amount = result;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer only solves one aspect of the problem. Note that answers are supposed to be **complete**, see [answer].

Comment: Question was to correct errors not to correct output.